# Rails Admin doesn't allow creating nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-admin

I have 3 models -> Actvities, Contacts, Phones

Activities has_many contacts

Contacts has_many phones

I am using rails_admin for CRUD functionality to add/edit activities.

In the /admin/activity/new page, rails_admin lists the contacts association and provides a button to add a new contact. This button opens a pop-up to add a new contact. But this new contact page doesn't provide any option to add a new phone.

However the /admin/contact/new page allows me to add a new phone.

Does rails_admin not support creating nested associations from a single page.

If that is the case is there any workaround for the same. Because I do not want /admin/contact and the /admin/phone pages to be accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails Admin allows this. I had to include

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts
```

in my Activity Model